# Difference between adding path variable in /etc/bash.bashrc and /home/user/.bashrc?

Tags: linux, variables, path

I tried to add path variables by adding following line to my bash.bashrc in /etc folder :

PATH=$PATH:/Folderpath

It didn't take the path for all variables in the folder but when i added the same thing in /home/user/.bashrc it started working?

Can anybody tell me as to whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The files in `/etc` are usually sourced by all the users. It might be possible that PATH is reinitialized later when sourcing more specifig rc files.